# Record Voice file Directly from a Browser

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3, red5, voice-recording

I am a looking for a free solution that would allow our website users to record voice files directly from our website. Instead of having to record it on their local machine then send it to us.

Comment: So what are your thoughts on Red 5?